# How to set a command as a dependency in waf

Tags: waf

I have a waf rule that does not create a file, so I don't have a target. I'd like another waf rule to be run strictly after the first rule. Below is a contrived example of this type of situation.

In Make syntax, I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
kill_server:
     myserver --kill

install_server: kill_server
     cp $(SRC)/myserver $(BLD)/myserver
```

In waf, I'm here:

```py
 def install_server(bld):
      killer = bld(name='kill_server', rule='myserver --kill')
      bld(name='install_server', rule='cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', 
          source=os.path.join(src, 'myserver'), 
          target=os.path.join(bld, 'myserver'), deps=[killer])
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because `killer` is TaskGen, not a target node. What *could* I put in deps? Can a step depend on another step that doesn't create a target?

Answer (score 1):

For rule based task generator, you can use the `after` keyword:

```py
def build(bld):

    bld(
        name = 'kill_server',
        rule = 'echo killing ...;sleep 5',
    )

    bld(
        name = 'install_server',
        rule = 'cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', 
        source = 'myserver', 
        target = 'myserver2',
        after = ["kill_server"]
    )
```

It works as rule based TG generate only one task with the TG name, and the `after` keyword is used for the task.

Another solution for other TG is to generate an output file and use it as a source for the dependant TG.

If source and target are the same, use waf Node API:

```
server = bld.path.find_node('myserver')
target_server = server.get_bld()
```

waf automatically manage the source tree vs the build tree.